# Bootstrap 3 Picture Carousel Stop Sliding and after going back to the first picture

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, asp.net-mvc-4, carousel

I have a picture carousel that is showing on the sidebar section of my page. The carousel works fine when the page first load, but it stops working after going back to the first picture of the slide. Am I missing something here?

```
//loading Jquery and bootstrap at the top of the page
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link href="../../Content/cosmo-boostrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/Site.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

The side section code in my HTML page:

```
<section id="sidebar" class="col-md-2">
                <div id="AddCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" data-wrap="true">
                      <!-- Indicators -->
                      <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                        <li data-target="#AddCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
                        <li data-target="#AddCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
                        <li data-target="#AddCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
                        <li data-target="#AddCarousel" data-slide-to="3"></li>
                      </ol>

                      <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
                      <div class="carousel-inner">
                        <div class="item active">
                          <img src="../../images/adds/Desert.jpg" alt="Desert">
                          <div class="carousel-caption">
                              <h3>Desert</h3>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="item">
                          <img src="../../images/adds/koala.png" alt="Koala">
                          <div class="carousel-caption">
                              <h3>Koala</h3>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="item">
                          <img src="../../images/adds/Jellyfish.jpg" alt="Jelly Fish">
                          <div class="carousel-caption">
                              <h3>Jelly Fish</h3>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="item">
                          <img src="../../images/adds/Tulips.jpg" alt="Tulips">
                          <div class="carousel-caption">
                              <h3>Tulips</h3>
                          </div>
                      </div>
                  </div>
                      <!-- Controls -->
                     @* <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
                      </a>
                      <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
                      </a>*@
              </div> <!-- Carousel -->
            </section>
```

jQuery function at the end of the page:

```
<script>
      $('.carousel').carousel({
        interval: 3000
      });
</script>
```

After the page load or refresh, the carousel looks fine. See below pic:

[image]

After going back to the first carousel, the carousel shows two pictures and stop sliding. See pic below:

[image]

Comment: Have you seen you have 2 indicators with data-slide-to="2" ?

Comment: Thanks @TheLittlePig, I updated it. The behavior did not change after updating it.

Comment: The data-ride="carousel" attribute is used to mark a carousel as animating starting at page load. It cannot be used in combination with (redundant and unnecessary) explicit JavaScript initialization of the same carousel(text copied from http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#carousel), so try remove the script

Comment: I tried both. I removed the data-ride="carousel" and leave the script. Then, I removed the script and leave the data-right="carousel". It did not change the behavior of the carousel.

Comment: check console probably you are getting a javascript error after 4rth slide

Comment: There is no javascript error message in my console.

Comment: I noticed that it did the same in Firefox and chromes but not in IE. In IE, it worked fine the first time too; the second time it showed the picture of the tulips but the jelly fish was active. When it showed the jelly fish, the Desert was active. It's not in sync.

Answer (score 0):

I removed the javascript code below, and it worked as expected now.

```
<script>
      $('.carousel').carousel({
        interval: 3000
      });
</script>
```